# mouseover style change with JQuery

Tags: jquery

taking the following html:

```
    <li>
    <p>
    <a href="#" class="link" ><img src="images/photo_cityguild_cropped.jpg" alt="Education" title="Education">
    <span class="label">E D U C A T I O N</span>
    </a>
    </p>
    </li>
```

I want to basically change the class of the `<span>` on the event of the user hovering over the image link.

I haven't got much use of JQuery under my belt and its been a while anyway, I was trying the following:

```
$(".link").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find("span").addclass("label2");
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find("span").removeclass("label2");
  });
```

could somebody indicate to me as to what I need to correct as it is currently doing nothing.

thanks,

**EDIT** updated with my solution.

implemented this code instead:

```
$(".link").live("mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
  if ( event.type == "mouseover" ) {
    $(this).find("span").addClass("label2");
  } else {
    $(this).find("span").removeClass("label2");
  }
});
```

Comment: i have corrected the syntax, however still I am getting nothing :S

Comment: do I have to remove the 'label' class before I can see the affect of label2?

Comment: Next time it would be helpful if you mention your HTML fragment is being dynamically appended to the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is with the method that you have called. It should be as suggested as above i.e. `addClass` and `removeClass`.

Also, i think you can refactor the code using `hover` event

```
$(".link").hover(function() {
  $(this).find("span").toggleClass("label2");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error. It's

```
addClass()
```

and

```
removeClass()
```

With uppercase 'C'.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead of mouseover/out, and find('span') instead of [children('span')](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Comment: I disagree with hover, myself.  I really don't think it's any more helpful than it's 'expanded' form.  I fully support using find instead of children, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
addClass and removeClass
```

notice the camelCasing

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript functions are case sensitive.

In this case `.addclass` should be `.addClass` and `.removeclass` should be `.removeClass`

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uq67C/1/

EDIT:

Your CSS is looking for elements with the class `label` and `label2` inside an element with an ID of `menu`. Something like:

```
<ul id="menu">   
<li>
    <p>
    <a href="#" class="link" ><img src="images/photo_cityguild_cropped.jpg" alt="Education" title="Education">
    <span class="label">E D U C A T I O N</span>
    </a>
    </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

should work.

Comment: I can see obviously this works, however for myself, still no luck after correcting the syntax :S

Comment: @buymypies What does your CSS look like?

Comment: my jquery is working, as I've tested its use otherwise, so something is not write with my syntax?

Comment: are you missing an element with the id of Menu? because when i removed `#menu` from in front of `.label` and `.label2` it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/Uq67C/4/